# Service Reference to third party is using arrays instead of generic lists

Tags: web-services, generics, c#-4.0, proxy

I saw similar posts related to my problem but found no answer. I've got a simple class library with a "service reference" to this amazon service: http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/AWSECommerceService.wsdl in my visual studio 2010 project. The project is using ".Net Framework 4" profile. Again this is a "service reference" **NOT** the old school "web reference". I've gone into the advanced options and told it to use "System.Collections.Generic.List" as the "collection type" but it ignores this and uses arrays for everything.

How do I get visual studio 2010 to generate a proxy for this particular service and get it to use generic lists? Are there command lines that will force this during the generation?

Example of what what I do **NOT** want:

```
    private ItemLink[] itemLinksField;
```

What I want the proxy generator to produce:

```
    private List<ItemLink> itemLinksField;
```

Comment: You could always write the proxy code by hand. It's not hard to do and it will result in cleaner code.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this, however there is simple way how to convert array of objects to list in just one line of code. See my sample code:

```
        //init WCF client...
        List<ItemLink> result = null;
        WFOperationsProvider.OperationsClient client = null;
        client = new WFOperationsProvider.OperationsClient();

        //get and convert array result to list...
        result = client.GetMyItems().OfType<ItemLink>().ToList();

        //close WCF client...
        client.Close();
```